# Laravel 5.3 Resource routes names

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I upgraded  my Laravel 5.2 application to Laravel 5.3. I have a lot of Resource routes like:

```
Route::resource('web/products', 'Web\ProductController', ['except' => ['show']]);
Route::resource('web/promos',   'Web\PromoController',   ['except' => ['show']]);
```

The route names generated for them until Laravel 5.2 were:

```
web.products.index
web.products.create
web.products.store
web.products.edit
web.products.update
web.products.edit
```

I used the route() helper to print all the routes by its name. The problem is that now Laravel 5.3 is generating my routes with this names:

```
products.index
products.create
products.store
products.edit
products.update
products.edit
```

I need them to be fully namespaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
Route::resource('web/products', 'Web\ProductController', ['names' => [
    'create' => 'web.products.create'
]]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can give "as" parameter in group directive for giving all group routes a prefix.

```
Route::group(['as'=>'web.'], function() {
    Route::resource('web/products', 'Web\ProductController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::resource('web/promos',   'Web\PromoController',   ['except' => ['show']]);
});
```

Also you can specify prefix for url

```
Route::group(['as'=>'web.','prefix'=>'web'], function() {
    Route::resource('products', 'Web\ProductController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::resource('promos',   'Web\PromoController',   ['except' => ['show']]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not wrap them in a group?

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Web'], function() {
    Route::resource('web/products', 'ProductController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::resource('web/promos',   'PromoController',   ['except' => ['show']]);
});
```

Comment: This only modifies the scope of controllers. I need the route names to be web.products.* instead of products.*

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that you're doing `web/products` -- is there a reason for that? If you change it to `web.products` I think that will give you the routes you're looking for.